# Scala - block can not contain declarations

Tags: scala

I have the following method where I am searching for the position of a character in a 2D vector.

```
  def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos = {
    var pos: Pos
    pos.x = levelVector.indexWhere(row => row.indexOf(c) > 0)
    pos.y = levelVector(pos.x).indexOf(c)
    pos
  }
```

`pos` has two integer fields which remember positions on the x and y axis

However, on the line `var pos: Pos` I am getting the error `Block cannot contain declarations`.

Why can't the block contain declarations?
Which is the issue with my code?

Comment: can you add stack trace ? the class Pos definition too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your problem is that you are writing 
`var pos:Pos`

you should write instead :

```
val pos = new Pos(...)
```

Anyway , while reading your code its kind of java written in scala. 
if you can be immutable, so be. 
in scala you should instantiante your class with the variables. which means you cannot change the state of the class i.e statements like

```
pos.x =  //something
pos.y =  //something
```

is changing the state of the variable pos. 
I would reccomend to be immutable 
i.e

```
val x = //something
val y = //something 
val newPos = Pos(x,y)
```

Have fun

Answer (score 8):

Complementing the selected answer, the problem with

```
var pos: Pos
```

is that `pos` was not initialized with anything (thus the "declaration" error).

These two initializations would be valid (for a general case):

```
var pos: Pos = null
// or
var pos: Pos = new Pos(...)
```

But in your case, you should use `val` followed by the constructor

```
val newPos = new Pos(...)
```

As mentioned, use immutability in Scala whenever is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve this issue, you need to define var pos: Pos=_ as a global variable in the class and you can call that variable within the function. Please refer to the example below

```
class ScalaPrintStatement {
var a: Int=_
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
println("The value of a is :"+a)
}
 }
```

Scala will not allow you to declare the variable without initializing within the function because scala does not like mutability, if you just declare the variable. you can immute it whenever you want.